# Do I need a Web Application Firewall if my APIs are protected with OAuth?

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, azure-functions, web-application-firewall, azure-waf

I implemented a micro-service model and each API is protected using bearer token authentication... no service logic is executed unless a valid OAuth token is provided as part of the request header.

What problem does using a Web Application Firewall to protect my APIs solve if only authenticated users are able to execute them?

Answer (score 0):

Client id's and secrets can leak.  Users can become disgruntled.  The WAF protects you in a situation where an authenticated user is attacking/probing the system.